# When we run which indexer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, reindex

I have large store in Magento 2 with 1000+ attributes. So it's take very long time to reindex all data.

So I want to know that which indexer I need to run for which changes.

```
catalog_category_product                 Category Products
catalog_product_category                 Product Categories
catalog_product_price                    Product Price
catalog_product_attribute                Product EAV
cataloginventory_stock                   Stock
catalogrule_rule                         Catalog Rule Product
catalogrule_product                      Catalog Product Rule
catalogsearch_fulltext                   Catalog Search
```

Can anyone help me to know that which indexer I need to run for which changes like If i change product stock then I need to run **cataloginventory_stock** indexer. But I don't know about other indexer.

**So anyone give me full description about these indexers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my note about Magento indexer

`catalog_product_attribute` - Product Attributes (If you updated attributes which are used layered navigation)

`catalog_category_product` - Category Products (If you added or removed products from catalog)

`catalog_product_price` - Product Prices (If you updated prices)

`catalogsearch_fulltext` - Catalog Search Index (If you updated searchable attributes of product)

`catalogrule_rule` - Catalog Rule Rule (If you updated condition,rule in Catalog Price Rule)

`catalogrule_product` - Catalog Rule Product (If you updated which product contain in rule)

Hope it help you! :)